# alternative to using global variable to store AsyncTask result

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an AsyncTask that returns a value in the onPostExecute method and the only way that i know how to get that returned value is to use a global member variable of the class and set that value in the onPostExecute method.

is there a better way or alternative way to do this?  what i am doing now requires the creation of many member variables for this reason only.

here is what I am doing now

```
  public class MainClass extends Activity {
  String takeInString = "";

  new DoItAsyncTask().execute(97);

  // nested inner class of AsyncTask inside of MainClass
  public class DoItAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, String>{
    String tempString = "";

      @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);

                  // assign value of global member variable takeInString
                 takeInString = result;

        }
    }

    @Override
      protected void onPreExecute() {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        Database dptr = new Database(MainClass.this);
        dptr.openToRead();
        tempString = dptr.getStringFromDatabase(params[0]);
        dptr.close();

        return tempString;

      }

} // end DoItAsyncTask

 } // end MainClass
```

Comment: What you want to do with this value after?

Comment: the strings will be used added to arraylists and these will be used to populate listview on different fragments.  so basically getting strings from a SQLite database and putting those strings into listviews.   so i need to use AsyncTask because it is bad form to do any database query on the UI thread

Comment: you can add values to array list from background as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way, pass `Object` instead `Integer` or `String`:

```
new DoItAsyncTask().execute(97, takeInString);

private class HeavyTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Void> {

private mLocalStrong = "";

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
   mLocalInt = (Integer)params[0];       
   mLocalStrong = (String)params[1];

    return null;
  }
```